# The version of component "x" is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, dataflowtask

Getting this error trying to run an SSIS Package on a 64 bit install of SS2K5 Enterprise Edition SP3.

Package was developed using 32 bit BIDS, and deployed successfully to 64 bit SS2K5 Enterprise Edition SP2, and 64 bit SS2K5 Developer Edition SP3.

Have upgraded client tools to SP3 with same result.

Amy ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error is caused by non having server binaries when you run dtexec.exe. However you've said it'a an EE install.

So: random guess...

Does it run on a 32 bit server install? You may be missing [x64 ODBC components](http://blogs.msdn.com/data/archive/2008/04/07/64-bit-oledb-provider-for-odbc-msdasql-is-now-available-for-windows-server-2003.aspx)

Remember: an SSIS package is just XML/text data so has no concept of x86/x64...